# What is a power series representation of $\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I got so far as to rewrite to this: $(1-x^2)\cdot \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}$ so that I can write the power series as follows:

$$(1-x^2)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \cdot x^{2n}$$

But how can I bring the constants on the left hand side into the sum in the proper way? This is part of an old exams paper, so it should, I suppose, come together "neatly"?

Thanks

Comment: Which "constants on the left hand side into the sum" are you talking of?

Comment: I think it is better to separate it as $\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$. Then you know the series on the left and you can get the right series derivating another series.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat sorry I didn't mean constants, I meant bring the sum product into the sum, if that makes sense. So that the whole could be represented as one sum, rather than a sum multiplied by $1-x^2$

Comment: $$(1-x^2)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \cdot x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \cdot x^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} \cdot x^{2n+2}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \cdot 2\cdot x^{2n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mkspk has a nice alternative approach in the comments, but, to answer your question, distribute the series $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$ into $1-x^2$, reindex, and combine the series:

\begin{align*}
(1-x^2)S &= S - x^2S \\
   &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+2}\\
   &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n}x^{2n}\\
   &= 1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice. I think this would also be doable in an exam. Thank you!!

Comment: @k4kuz0: Happy to help! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=1-\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}$.

Now use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k}$$
To get
$$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=1-\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}=1-2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k+2}$$